# Perl using Wx yields core dump in debug mode (option -d)

Tags: perl, wxperl

I have the following 3 line example to show the error:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Wx;
```

It works fine when I run it with `perl -w hue5.pl`. However, when I add the debugging option and start if with `perl -w -d hue5.pl`, a problem emerges and perl runtime crashes saying:

> Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.55
> Editor support available.
>
> Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.
>
> Wx::CODE(0x5604c197ca80)(/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Wx.pm:154):
> 154:    UnsetConstants() if defined &UnsetConstants;
> double free or corruption (!prev)
> Aborted (core dumped)

I use perl v5.30.3 on 64 bit Linux (up-to-date Fedora release 31) and Wx installed from the binary package perl-Wx-0.9932-15.fc31.x86_64.rpm.

Is anybody else having this issue?

Comment: Works fine (no crash) on Ubuntu 20.04, perl version 5.30.0, Wx version 0.9932 [downloaded](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MD/MDOOTSON/Wx-0.9932.tar.gz) and installed from source. The debugger stops at [line 154](/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/site_perl/5.30.0/x86_64-linux/Wx.pm:154) in `Wx.pm`

Comment: Also works fine on Debian 10.4 using perl v5.28.1 with Wx 0.9932 (installed as the default binary packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: Uninstalling the package `perl-Term-ReadLine-Gnu` solved the issue.

Longer version: I saw that the issue does not always happen. In fact, it seems to depend on the size of the process environment. At one point of debugging I could make the crash appear by declaring in the `bash` (note: without `export` the issue does not show)

```
export SOMEVAR=xyz
```

and disappear by

```
unset SOMEVAR
```

Finally, during further experimentation, I once got a more elaborate failure message pointing right to Readline/Gnu:

> Signal SEGV at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm line 504.
> Term::ReadLine::Gnu::ornaments(Term::ReadLine=HASH(0x5593c12e5190), 1) > called at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm line 301
> Term::ReadLine::Gnu::new("Term::ReadLine", "perldb", GLOB(0x5593c062df58), GLOB(0x5593c05c6ea8)) called at /usr/share/perl5/perl5db.pl line 6865
> DB::setterm() called at /usr/share/perl5/perl5db.pl line 1849
> DB::_DB__read_next_cmd(undef) called at /usr/share/perl5/perl5db.pl line 2789
> DB::DB called at f.pl line 5

For the *curious*, I note that line 504 in /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm was:

```
return Term::ReadLine::Gnu::XS::ornaments(@_);
```

For the *even more curious* I add `strace` dumps generated by runs which differ only with regard to the absence/presence of `SOMEVAR` in the environment (note that the name does not seem to have importance, I first got into the direction of environment differences by observing different behaviour depending on `OLDPWD`).

First without the issue (i.e. without variable `SOMEVAR`), quoting the lines as of loading Readline/Gnu library:

```
stat("/usr/lib65/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Term/ReadLine/Gnu/XS/autosplit.ix", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1137, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Term/ReadLine/Gnu/XS/autosplit.ix", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 13
ioctl(13, TCGETS, 0x7fff0a1cac70)       = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(13, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0
read(13, "# Index created by AutoSplit for"..., 8192) = 1137
read(13, "", 8192)                      = 0
close(13)                               = 0
lseek(3, 2189, SEEK_SET)                = 2189
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 2189
close(3)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl(5, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
stat("/home/bernhard/.terminfo", 0x55ec16193000) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access("/etc/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", R_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3808, ...}) = 0
read(3, "\36\2%\0&\0\17\0\235\0010\6xterm-256color|xterm"..., 32768) = 3808
read(3, "", 28672)                      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=43, ws_col=173, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=43, ws_col=173, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=43, ws_col=173, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCSWINSZ, {ws_row=43, ws_col=173, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/bernhard/.inputrc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/inputrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=943, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# do not bell on tab-completion\n"..., 943) = 943
close(3)                                = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55ec1640f000
brk(0x55ec16430000)                     = 0x55ec16430000
stat("/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Term/ReadLine/Gnu/XS/ornaments.al", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1351, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
getgroups(0, NULL)                      = 2
getgroups(2, [18, 1000])                = 2
stat("/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Term/ReadLine/Gnu/XS/ornaments.al", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1351, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Term/ReadLine/Gnu/XS/ornaments.al", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7fff0a1cb9d0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(3, "# NOTE: Derived from blib/lib/Te"..., 8192) = 1351
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
getpid()                                = 4060
getpid()                                = 4060
ioctl(4, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=43, ws_col=173, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCSWINSZ, {ws_row=43, ws_col=173, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP INT QUIT ALRM TERM TSTP TTIN TTOU], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da22f0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(0x5, 0), ...}) = 0
ioctl(5, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
write(5, "\33[4m  DB<1> \33[24m", 17)   = 17
pselect6(5, [4], NULL, NULL, NULL, {[], 8}) = 1 (in [4])
read(4, "q", 1)                         = 1
select(5, [4], NULL, [4], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
write(5, "q", 1)                        = 1
pselect6(5, [4], NULL, NULL, NULL, {[], 8}) = 1 (in [4])
read(4, "\r", 1)                        = 1
write(5, "\n", 1)                       = 1
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da2e70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, {sa_handler=0x7f4433da22f0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f44490e46b0}, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Second with the issue (i.e. wit exported variable `SOMEVAR`), again quoting only the lines as of loading Readline/Gnu library:

```
stat("/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Term/ReadLine/Gnu/XS/autosplit.ix", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1137, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Term/ReadLine/Gnu/XS/autosplit.ix", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 13
ioctl(13, TCGETS, 0x7ffe8bf62e00)       = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(13, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0
read(13, "# Index created by AutoSplit for"..., 8192) = 1137
read(13, "", 8192)                      = 0
close(13)                               = 0
lseek(3, 2189, SEEK_SET)                = 2189
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 2189
close(3)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl(5, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
stat("/home/bernhard/.terminfo", 0x55b600a2b5a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access("/etc/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", R_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3808, ...}) = 0
read(3, "\36\2%\0&\0\17\0\235\0010\6xterm-256color|xterm"..., 32768) = 3808
read(3, "", 28672)                      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=43, ws_col=173, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=43, ws_col=173, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
writev(2, [{iov_base="double free or corruption (!prev"..., iov_len=33}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 2) = 34
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f376a2e3000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
getpid()                                = 4029
gettid()                                = 4029
tgkill(4029, 4029, SIGABRT)             = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=4029, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
```